# How does an application like Wireshark work?

Tags: wireshark, software-design

Im am wondering how wireshark functions. What would be the design of an application that could listen to the traffic on all ports of a given machine? What is the kind of overheard that such an application generates? What would be a good way to go about writing an app that monitors traffic?

Thanks

Comment: I thought the magic with Wireshark comes from the WinPcap driver and library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wireshark leverages libpcap on unix platforms and its port WinPcap on Windows. This library provides an API to capture packets (Wireshark is also able to capture frames but I haven't found in pcap docs that pcap is able to do that).

How the library does that is platform-specific, that's why a good way would be to use the library to do the heavy lifting for you; libpcap or tcpdump on unix (depending on how low-level you need it to be) and WinPcap or Windows Filtering Platform on Windows.

Documentation:
http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap3_man.html
http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/main.html

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the [Windows Filtering Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366510.aspx) (this is for Vista+, but a similar feature was possible in XP- - the WFP just makes things easier). The WFP lets you listen to "callouts" in the driver that call your code at various points in the packet-processing stack so that you can capture, filter, and even modify the data as it moves around.